# Setting attribute using HTMLRewriter on Cloudflare worker

Tags: javascript, cloudflare-workers

I am trying to set the value attribute of my #email field via a Cloudflare worker.

I define my email as `test@test.com` but how can I send this into `ElementHandler` ?

At the moment I am able to set the value attribute to be `XXXX` and this works successfully.

```
async function handleRequest(request) {

  const newResponse = new Response(response.body, response)

  const email = 'test@test.com';

  return new HTMLRewriter()
     .on("#email", new ElementHandler())
     .transform(newResponse)

}

class ElementHandler {
   element(e) {
     e.setAttribute('value', 'XXXX')
   }
}

addEventListener("fetch", event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give your `ElementHandler` class a constructor that accepts parameters which you store in properties of the object:

```js
class ElementHandler {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  element(e) {
    e.setAttribute('value', this.value)
  }
}
```

Then construct it like:

```js
new ElementHandler(email)
```